# Namespace file not updating in Golem shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, golem

I am building my first Golem shiny app. I am currently using `usethis::use_package("shinydashboard")` and then `attachment::att_amend_desc()` to update the Description and Namespace file. However, I'm running into this message in the console:

```
Writing NAMESPACE
Writing NAMESPACE
i Loading app
[-] 8 package(s) removed: dashboardthemes, DBI, dplyr, pool, readxl, shinydashboard, shinyWidgets.
```

Why are the packages being removed?

Here are the relevant lines in the `02_dev.R` file:

```
# Engineering

## Dependencies ----
## Add one line by package you want to add as dependency"
usethis::use_package("shinydashboard")
usethis::use_package("dplyr")
usethis::use_package("readxl")
usethis::use_package("shinyWidgets")
usethis::use_package("dashboardthemes")
usethis::use_package("pool")
usethis::use_package("DBI")


## Amend DESCRIPTION with dependencies read from package code parsing
## install.package('attachment') # if needed.
attachment::att_amend_desc()
```

Comment: The packages are being removed by the function `attachment::att_amend_desc()`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `@import shinydashboard` command in your modules, then use `this::use_package("shinydashboard")` and `attachment::att_amend_desc()`.